# How do I type the tick and backtick characters on Windows?

Tags: windows, typing

How do I type tick and backtick on Windows?

Comment: What keyboard layout do you have? For US QWERTY, the backtick is they key to the left of the numeral "1". There is no "tick", but you may mean the single quote which on a US QWERTY keyboard is between the Enter key and the semicolon.

Comment: I need to know this for the screen based Windows 8 keyboard, so I have asked this again specifically about that keyboard: http://superuser.com/q/663134/166855

Comment: @JakeGould Interestingly enough the post you mention actually doesn't have the proper "alt code" for acute accent.

Comment: On my Turkish QWERTY keyboard, when I press `Alt-Gr` + `,`, it writes backtick`,

Answer (score 189, accepted):

## Backtick (grave accent)

#### QWERTY

Key that’s been marked with red border. It’s a [dead key](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) by default.

> [image: QWERTY]

This also applies to the Slovak QWERTZ layout.

---

#### QWERTZ Germany & Austria

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Key that's been marked with red border

> [image: German QWERTZ layout]

---

#### QWERTZ Switzerland

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Key that's been marked with a red border

> [image: Swiss QWERTZ layout]

---

#### QWERTZ Czech Republic and South Slavic Latin (Bosnian, Croatian, Serbian, Slovene)

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + Key that's been marked with red border

> [image: Czech QWERTZ layout]

---

#### QWERTZ Hungary

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + Key that's been marked with red border

> [image: Hungarian QWERTZ layout]

---

#### AZERTY France

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + Key that’s been marked with red border

> [image: AZERTY France]

---

#### AZERTY Belgium

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + Key that’s been marked with red border

> [image: AZERTY Belgium]

---

## Forwardtick (acute accent)

#### AZERTY Belgium

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + Key that’s been marked with red border

> [image: AZERTY Belgium]

---

## Alt codes

There may not be forwardtick keys available for the other keyboards, however an alt code exists (Hold left <kbd>Alt</kbd> and type the numbers on your num pad).

The below codes should work on any keyboard.

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 96 = `` ` ``
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0180 = `´`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 39 = `'`

So if you want an `'`, you do the following: Hold left <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press
<kbd>3</kbd>, release <kbd>3</kbd> but still hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press
<kbd>9</kbd>, release <kbd>9</kbd>, release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

[Unicode Character 'ACUTE ACCENT'](http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b4)

Comment: -1 u put all this effort in getting the images,even a red border aroudn the key,but the relevant mark on the key is so tiny it's hard2see what it is and in some cases look like a dot or dirt on my screen!They r extremely unclear images with a highlighted border around a key creating the illusion of clarity cos normally a highlight around an area clearly shows the thing it is around.i'm not even sure that'forwardtick'is a proper name. And the pictures just show specks! That red speck on the belgium keyboard key has a black speck too.I can only just ascertain which direction red speck is going

Comment: And the french keyboard image with the 7 and the e, and a tiny tiny little speck, that is the worst of all the bad pics you have there. Even clicking the image doesn't help in ascertaining what that character -you have highlighted- is!! Makes me wonder why you even bothered to highlight it. You may as well have said hit the 7 key it has a tick going one way or the other, that you want. Reading your answer carefully  I see the french one is a bad tick , from titled backtick at the top, but the image doesn't help at all in showing whether it's back or forward.

Comment: @barlop it's about the location which should be the same on all keyboards of the same localisation.

Comment: what is 0180? What character is that?

Comment: for the lazy that do not want to read the linked wiki article: press space after you’ve typed the backtick to have it typed/shown

Comment: I don't think that first one is representative of QWERTZ. The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ) shows only Slovak QWERTZ as having the backtick in that position; the Swiss, German, and Polish QWERTZ layouts have the backtick key to the left of the backspace, and the others don't appear to have a dedicated backtick key.

Comment: one of the best answers iv seen so far in this platform , well organized with user-friendly pictures and everything ☺

Answer (score 9):

Italian - Italy keyboard have no backtick key assigned.

...but it can be easily added by creating a new keyboard layout with [Microsoft Keyboard layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134)

I suggest to map it like in Linux with the AltGr+? key combination.

1. Install & run
2. Add key ALT+096 on the AltGr+? key combination
3. Generate setup
4. Launch setup and install the new keyboard
5. Select the new keyboard layout from Language and keyboard in Windows control panel

Comment: There is also Italian 142 keyboard that has backtick.

Comment: @CarLaTeX correct it is AltGr + ù but it also messes up the default AltGr keys

Comment: @Enos Yes, but it's a matter of habit, I use it without problems.

Answer (score 6):

On a Hungarian keyboard the backtick character is available via <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>).

Answer (score 4):

On German keyboard, backtick <kbd>´</kbd> is on the left to <kbd>backspace</kbd>
, or right to <kbd>ß</kbd> key.

You need to press that key and then press <kbd>space</kbd> to show up the <kbd>´</kbd> character.

[image]

Comment: For the [backtick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick) (ASCII 96, 0x60), you have to combine this key with the **Shift** key. What you are actually describing is the [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent).

Answer (score 3):

Norwegian keyboards has the backtick as a dead character. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + the key left of the <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Image here:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Brazilian `ABNT2` keyboards, the back tick key is the key between <kbd>P</kbd> and the key which has these symbols `[/{`.

It is also know as *grave accent*.
To use it, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> and then <kbd>space</kbd>.

*Brazilian Portuguese translation*:

Também é conhecido como *acento grave*.
Para usá-lo, pressione <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> e então <kbd>Sace</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

While <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> is enabled hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and type `0180` on the keypad then release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.  This will result in a forwardtick/acute accent.

Answer (score 1):

Fancy Logitech keyboard:

> right <kbd>Fn</kbd> + Top `left` key.

Answer (score 1):

Qwerty-latinoamericano layout:

Hold <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and press *twice* the button that has these symbols: `]}`

Full shortcut:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + `]}` x 2

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was missing for the **Spanish** keyboard. 
It is: <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Spanish - Spain: QWERTY keyboard layout (slightly different to Latin American Spanish layout)

Its the default value for the key marked with <kbd>[</kbd> althoughit is still a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key)

[image: QWERTY keyboard layout - Spanish (Spain)]

Answer (score 0):

**QWERTZ**:
On my keyboard the acute accent is at <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>: `´`

Accepted answer's key gives me `¸`

[image: QWERTZ layout]

Answer (score 0):

**QWERTY** for Turkish keyboard, press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> (Semicolon) key combination and then press <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why nobody suggested this solution, as it is in my opinion the most Windows-native and all the others are not really generic (e.g. they don't work for my italian keyboard without numeric keypad).

Windows PowerToys have a tool to easily remap the keyboard, you can install the package from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/install

This work on Windows 10/11, but I have some recollection I had used it succesfully on previous versione.