# How do I type the backtick / Grave accent character on a (UK) Windows 8 touch keyboard?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, special-characters

How do I type backtick (i.e. `) on a [Windows 8 touch keyboard](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/using-touch-keyboard)?

This is a similar question to [How do I type the tick and backtick characters on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/254076/166855) but the answer there covers real physical keyboard configurations while I need the Windows 8 virtual screen keyboard.

Here are some screen-shots of the keyboard that I am asking about:

[image: Windows 8 touch keyboard]

[image: Windows 8 touch keyboard]

[image: Windows 8 touch keyboard]

Comment: This isn't as pressing as it was a few days ago (I've replaced the backtick in my password with another symbol) but I would like to know the answer, not least because backtick is useful for formatting stackoverflow questions and answers.

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using - English ? Do you have a key for the backtick (Grave accent)? If yes, does pressing it and then Space give the right result?

Comment: I've added screenshots. As far as I can tell it is not there though I'm hoping that someone knows a sneaky way to type it on that keyboard.

Comment: Can you in PC Settings, under Touch keyboard, see some options to turn on so to have more keys on this keyboard? There might be an option named "show standard keyboard".

Comment: I cannot see any - the control panel settings for the mouse and keyboard just give me mouse stuff, the regional settings have nowt.

Comment: Are you looking in the Modern settings, like [this](http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tablet-touch/4430d1331736070t-windows-8-touch-keyboard-option-change-keyboard-type-gone-settings.png) ?

Comment: I wasn't but checking there I too only see the options on the screenshot you referenced: on/off toggles for the on-screen keyboard, the sticky keys, toggle key tones, and filter keys.

Comment: No "Make the standard keyboard layout available" ?

Comment: Wow - I was looking under PC Settings -> Ease of Access -> Keyboard but after your comment I have rooted around more and under PC Settings -> PC and devices -> Typing at the end there is indeed an option to "Make the standard keyboard layout available" and with that turned on I can swap to the full keyboard and type ` into a text field like the surface's password prompt. *THANK YOU* If you copy that over to an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default touch keyboard in Windows 8 is quite simple and destined to be used
on small screens.

The article
[How to Make the Standard Keyboard Layout Available in Windows 8 Touch Keyboard](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/24398-touch-keyboard-add-standard-keyboard-layout-windows-8-a.html)
describes how to replace it by the full keyboard.

To add the standard keyboard layout to touch keyboard in Windows 8 :

1. Open **PC Settings**
2. Click/tap on **General** on the left side
3. On the right side under **Touch keyboard**, move the slider on the right to the end
   of the list
4. Turn on **Make the standard keyboard layout available**
5. When finished, you can close PC Settings.

On Windows 8.1, this setting has migrated to **PC Settings** -> **PC and devices** -> **Typing**.

[image]