# Excel cells remain blank after entering formula and pressing enter?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have been facing a rather strange problem in Excel - it's not easy to explain so I have also attached a screenshot to help

[image: ScreenShot]

When I type a formula into a cell and press 'Enter', the formula executes but the answer does not appear immediately in the cell. Instead, I have to click on some other cell, or perform some other operation for that number to show up. This does not happen when the cells included in the formula are on the screen. For example, if I were to input "=A1+A2" into A3 and press 'Enter', the answer would appear. However, if I were to input "=A1+A2" into A27 (where A1 and A2 are not visible on screen) and press 'Enter', the cell will remain blank until I double click it or perform some other operation!

This has really been driving me crazy! Does anyone have any possible explanation or solution to this? For what it's worth, I'm on Excel 2016 for Mac.

Comment: There are better tools to do screenshots. It happens to me. Exiting excel and restarting it usually solve it. Sometimes there are some changes in settings (e.g. by pressing wrong key combination), but if this is the case, I left other to answer

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The issue is when I try to do a screenshot on my laptop, the number in the blank cell appears. Hence I was forced to take an image! I have tried restarting excel a few times, but to no avail.

Comment: For me also the cell `A27` has a strange formatting.  Now I remember: once this was due to formatting of cell. Try to force it as number (Control-1). Sometime excel go crazy with a forced text format. If it works, you can copy empty cells (just below everithing) to the affected range of cells.

Comment: Yup! When I change all the cells to 'Number' as a format, the problem goes away. Do you know how to make 'Number' as the default format for cells as compared to 'General'?

Comment: No, I don't know. Usually *General* is good. Only few times excel messes up things (especially if files is saved using several different versions of excel). I would recommend you to create a new file, copy all content of actual file, pasting without formatting, and then applying manually formatting.  I don't have a real solution, nor I understand what it is the real problem.

Comment: Is Workbook Calculations set to "Automatic" in options?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi please write up an answer so that Tiffany can accept a solution. Seems this one is all figured out now.

Comment: hey press the print screen shortcut key on your keyboard, not the capture button on camera

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a problem with cell formatting. It happens seldom (and in my experience, when working on the same file with different microsoft excel versions, or automatically generated by other microsoft tools (e.g. microsoft access)).

To solve the problem, you need to select the cells that doesn't display numbers, and select the cell format as "General" or "Numbers". Note: in general microsoft excel does a good job on interpreting the correct format of a cell, just few time it become stubborn.

See also the answer of Hannu (not the first one, unfortunatelly) in
[Cells show formula, not formula result](https://superuser.com/questions/811265/cells-show-formula-not-formula-result).

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing this same problem.  It has been driving me crazy.  It only started a few months ago in an ongoing spreadsheet I have, so I'm thinking it's a bug in an Office 365 update a while ago.

But reading some answers above gave me some hints.  I have panes frozen so that rows 1-5 remain visible.  Sometimes I work on a minimized screen when I don't have a second monitor to connect to so that I can see data to be entered on and then enter it on the excel document.  Whenever I do this, and the formula was off screen, and I entered data in a cell that is ON screen, the formula simply would not update.  I would have to maximize the document, and copy the formula down the column again.

I couldn't see how this would be the problem, but I tried it anyway:  I unfroze all pane, then minimized the screen, and entered data in the cells visible on screen.  Sure as anything, the formula - even though it is not visible on the screen - now updates!  Tested this ridiculous thing a few times, and that's definitely the cause.  Why?  I have no idea.  But it's a work-around.

Hope this is clear as mud.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

7/3/2020:  I was having same problem.  Just figured out how to fix.  In my case, I had calculated cells in rows 1 to 13 that were frozen with "freeze pane".  My xls showed rows 1-13 at the top then rows 75-97 at the bottom, for example.  The first 13 rows were frozen with freeze pane.  When I typed F2 to edit a formula in the first 13 rows, then hit escape after not making changes, the output of this cell would go blank, even though it appeared immediately before hitting F2!  To fix this, instead if hitting escape when no changes were made, I hit return instead.  And problem is gone!  Escape normally would be okay if "freeze pain" were removed.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  You seem to be saying that the answer is to hit return (a.k.a. 'Enter').  But the question says that the problem *occurs* when the user presses 'Enter'.

Comment: This is perhaps an interesting issue (I haven't tested it), but it doesn't sound like it's the same issue that OP was describing.  If you have this problem, perhaps post your own question (and answer it as well)?

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises because you moved some cells from one place to another, which causes the `Sum` formula of these cells expand to cells (up or down) - depends on where you move the cell.

Suppose you have some rows `A1` to `A10` and you put `Sum` formula after these rows, and you also have another data at `A12` to `A20`, now you move any cell from first series to below may be to `A15` or end of `A20`, the `Total` of `A1` to `10` expands to `A1` to `A20` and you face this problem. Just `Sum` the cells again and it will be solved, hope that answer helpful.