# How do I type the forwardtick—opposite of backtick—characters on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I’m not sure if I'm using the right terminology but I think what I am looking for is a forwardtick. It is the opposite direction of a backtick sometimes called a [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent). So how do I type this and what is it called? Is there an alt code?

[image]

Comment: @JakeGould Why did you mark this as duplicate?  The question marked asks specifically about tick and backtick.  While the answer given references the acute accent it does not have the correct alt code for windows.  Did you even try the alt code (alt+239) given in the answer?  The alt code given results in "∩".  The question linked DOES NOT have the correct "alt code" for the acute accent.

Comment: @Goblinlord I am not the only one who marked this as duplicate DavidPostill, ᔕᖺᘎᕊ and Mokubai did this as well. If you believe [the other question—and related answer—is incorrect](http://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows), please post an answer or comment there. But bugging one person over the period of a week about this is not a great way to make your pount.